# What is Rhino Mocks Repeat?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

What is Rhino Mocks Repeat ?

```
Repeat.Any();

Repeat.Once();
```

What does it mean and how it works ?

Comment: Repeat.Once seems a little self-contradictory ;)

Comment: Could someone provide an answer in terms of AAA syntax? For example, stubbing a mock?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is used with the `Expect` construct as part of a fluent declaration. As for what it means: it means that the previous event is expected to occur that many times.

For instance: `Expect.Call(someMethod()).Repeat.Twice()` says that `someMethod()` will be called exactly two times.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887245/rhino-mocks-repeat-once-not-working) post explains it very well, at least from my own experience where I found the fluent API a bit confusing.