# Rhino Mocks: Repeat.Once() not working?

Tags: rhino-mocks

Can anyone tell me why in the world the following test is not failing?

```
[Test]
public void uhh_what() {
    var a = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IPrebuiltNotifier>();
    a.Expect(x => x.Notify()).Repeat.Once();
    a.Notify();
    a.Notify();
    a.VerifyAllExpectations();
}
```

Really need a second pair of eyes to confirm I'm not crazy...now I'm worried that all my tests are unreliable.

Comment: For future reference ([albeit Rhino mock is old](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-mocks)) I add that 'Stub'-'Once'-'VerifyAllExpectations' as in `mock.Stub(x => x.Notify()).Repeat.Once();` also does not work as expected. Instead [`AssertWasCalled`](https://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2009/06/23/rhinomocks-repeat-times/) should be used.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is already a [thread on the RhinoMocks group](http://groups.google.com/group/RhinoMocks/browse_thread/thread/13abb06b8893ade8/9a1d0473f18f54c9).

GenerateMock creates a dynamic mock. The dynamic mock allows calls that are not specified (=expected). If this happens, it just returns null (or the default value of the return type).

Note: **Repeat is a specification of the behaviour (like Stub), not the expectation** even if specified in an expectation.

If you want to avoid having more then a certain number of calls, you could write:

```
[Test]
public void uhh_what() 
{
    var a = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IPrebuiltNotifier>();
    a.Expect(x => x.Notify()).Repeat.Once();
    a.Stub(x => x.Notify()).Throw(new InvalidOperationException("gotcha"));
    a.Notify();

    // this fails
    a.Notify();

    a.VerifyAllExpectations();
}
```

Or

```
[Test]
public void uhh_what() 
{
    var a = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IPrebuiltNotifier>();
    a.Notify();
    a.Notify();

    // this fails
    a.AssertWasCalled(
      x => x.Notify(), 
      o => o.Repeat.Once());
}
```

Comment: oh!  I didn't know that AssertWasCalled had a second argument where you could do more specifications, this changes everything!

Comment: It is the same issue with PartialMock, if you ever step on it.

Comment: The first solution (where you throw an exception) _will_ make the test fail if `Notify` is called more than once. However, if it's only called once (at least that's what I assume the code under test should do), the test won't pass as it should because it's expecting a _second_ call to `Notify` that never comes. Set up `a.Expect(x => x.Notify()).Repeat.Once()` followed by `a.Stub(x => x.Notify()).Throws(...)` to do the job.

Comment: @geoffmazeroff: you are right. This answer exists for more than 2 years and nobody ever recognized it ... Thanks, I fix it.

Answer (score 9):

When using GenerateMock (or with Dynamic Mocks in general) I always mentally insert the following:

a.Expect(x => x.Notify()).Repeat.***[AtLeast]***Once();